# Jquery find a .parents() a tag and addClass

Tags: jquery, siblings

I have been trying to target a `.parents()` a tag

I am using this code -

```
$('#nav li li:has(a.current)').parents('li').find('a').addClass('current');
```

It does target the parents a tag and add the correct class but it also adds the class to all its siblings.

Any tips on why I am also getting siblings?

[Check out the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/webthread/dDqhU/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you only want the `A` that is the child of the parent, switch `find()` to `children()`

```
$('#nav li li:has(a.current)').parents('li').children('a').addClass('current');
```

Comment: not sure which element you want to target...may need more refinement depending on what you are after

Comment: Nope, that's spot on, I wanted to target the parent li's A. It's just to show a current state when a sibling is current.

Answer (score 1):

Start with the `.current` anchor, find the closest `UL` surrounding the list, find the parent `LI`, and then use `children('a')` to get direct children anchors, as `find()` will find all anchors, and add the class, like so:

```
$('#nav a.current').closest('ul').parent('li').children('a').addClass('current');​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/dDqhU/5/)

Comment: This also works, any advantage to this and @charlietfl answer?

Comment: @Nik - It does'nt use pseudo selectors, and it does'nt search the entire DOM for parent li elements.